# enable --display-error-details in webpack to debug module imports

Tags: node.js, webpack-cli

working on an issue where I need to enable this webpack.stats options for the cli for debugging purposes.

On the base webpack.config there is no stats options enabled so it needs to be done another way.

The devServer is also separated into it's own .js file and not listed under the default webpack.config

I've tried to directly add this setting into the base webpack configuration, I've also researched and reviewed the functionality under dev-server to see if it's a setting I can just add a line of code to, but no luck. For example I reviewed into stats.hasErrors() function and learned about the option

```
stats.toJson({
errorDetails: true
})
```

What I believe to be the relevant parts of the code that need to be updated
**dev-server.js**

```
).then(config => {
    if (options.debugWebpack) {
      logConfig('Manager webpack config', config, logger);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      webpack(config).watch(
        {
          aggregateTimeout: 1,
        },
        (err, stats) => {
          managerTotalTime = process.hrtime(startTime);
          if (!resolved && (err || stats.hasErrors())) {
            const error = new Error('Manager build is broken');
            error.error = err;
            error.close = true;
            error.stats = stats;
            logger.line();
            logger.line();
```

I want to be able to run something like the following:

```
yarn storybook --display-error-details
```

Link to the repo:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/next/lib/core/src/server
Thanks for any help provided!

Answer (score 0):

So I got an approval from the repo by doing the following:
**dev-server.js**

```
 managerTotalTime = process.hrtime(startTime);
          if (!resolved && (err || stats.hasErrors())) {
            const error = new Error('Manager build is broken');
            error.error = err;
            error.close = true;
            error.stats = stats;
            stats.toJson({
               errorDetails: true
            })
            logger.line();
            logger.line();
```